# How can I save React state on rerender?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a simple shop in react and I've run into a little problem.
Every time I click the Element it changes to true (like intended), but when I resize the window everything resets back to false. I thought that class components save the variables and don't reset back like functional components.

How can I implement it, so that it saves the checked variable?

Second Question:

How would I be able to add an object of the class Item into a useState array?
My thought process:

1. Click the Element you want to add to the shopping cart
2. Set checked variable so I can display a checkbox on the Item
3. Something like `setShoppingCart(shoppingCart =>(...shoppingCart,this))` where shoppingCart is a useState array
4. And then have a  `useEffect(()=>{shoppingCart.map((e) => (<span>e.offerId<span/>))},shoppingCart])` 
   Please Help me :)

```
class Item extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.name = props.name
            this.preis = props.preis
            this.dauer = props.dauer
            this.offerId = props.offerId
            this.state = {
                checked: false
            };
        }

        changeState() {
            this.setState({checked : !this.state.checked})
            console.log(this.state.checked)
        }


        render() {

            return (
                <>
                    <div onClick={() => this.changeState()} className={style.Item + ' m-2 p-3'}>
                        {this.name} {this.preis} {this.dauer} {this.offerId} {this.state.checked ? "true" : "false"}
                    </div>
                </>
            )
        }

    }
```

Edit: 
Here is the whole code [GitHub](https://github.com/M4xiGitHub/StackOverflow/blob/main/question.js)

Comment: "when I resize the window everything resets back to false" is very unexpected behavior; this should have no effect on react state unless you have some handler running on the resize event?

Comment: No, I don't have a resize handler. Maby It's the way I create them? I have an array with all my json data for every item and I just map over it with <Item name="..." offerId="..."/>

Comment: I edited the post and added a link to my whole Code. I'm sorry if it's bad just starting to learn to react.  Maby its a very obvious answer and I just don't have the experience